# Does TP-Link TL-WR543G support WPS? If so, can it be turned off?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wps

I have a TP-Link TL-WR543G router that has been purchased around 2011. I tried to find some WPS-related settings and turn them off, but unfortunately I cannot find any such option in the web interface.

The router reports that its exact model is `WR543G v2`. The firmware version is `3.7.1 Build 080904`, and it [seems to be up to date](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WR543G_V2.html#Firmware). I've come across this [RouterCheck page](http://support.routercheck.com/TP-LINK/TL-WR543G/WPS-0.html), but despite having this particular router model in the title, it only contains generic instructions on where to look for the option ("it could be in Wi-Fi settings...").

So, I have two questions:

- **Does this router implement WPS?**
- **If yes, is it possible for me to turn it off?**

Comment: If you can believe the router manual http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/2008716160729.pdf, then no. It makes no mention of WPS or Protected Setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [User Guide](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/2008716160729.pdf) provided by TP-LINK, WPS does not seem to be supported by this router.

Comment: I guess that's good enough for me.